# Jquery Autocomplete field values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, autocomplete

I am using jquery's autocomplete and the values are populated via SQL thru ajax calls. I would like to restrict the inputs on this field to be only those that are on the autocomplete list. Meaning if the sql returned 'A, B, C', the value D shouldnt be accepted.

I can do this by making additional queries backend but I am wondering if there is a simpler way and a more efficient way of achieving this.

Comment: So you want to validate the user input?

Comment: Yes, ideally that's what I would want to happen. I figure that using a dropdown lsit is better but autocomplete input just looks aesthetically better for me @AndrosRex

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do user validation on the client side. You can easily check if the value being submitted and it doesn't correspond to any of the shown values, show some kind of an "error" message and use .preventDefault() to stop the data from being sent. This, however, is only for a better user experience. Everyone can still modify the JS code and send the invalid data nevertheless. You don't necessarily have to do this validation - the users can manage without it, too.

This is why the validation with the goal of security and lack of bugs is on the server side. If by sending invalid data a user can damage a table or even the entire database, then you must definitely validate it server-side too.

Comment: Currently, the way I validate it is by making another query then checking if the submitted value is in the list returned by the query for the autocomplete. I was just wondering if there's a simple js/jquery function to do this like .onlySourceFields: true , or something similar (maybe even a javascript/jquery function that wouldnt necessarily need to do another query, just reuse values from the autocomplete list). I think me doing another query to check might be an unnecessary load in my database. If there's no other way to do this then I'd just stick with my current implementation, then. Thx

Comment: @Bennjoe Mordeno Why don't you have a list in your JS code where you keep the results from the current autocomplete, so while validating, all you do is test if the input value corresponds to anything in it?